# How do I decrypt a password protected, BIP0038 address?

Tags: paper-wallet

Services like bitaddress.org allow you to password encrypt a paper wallet. How would I decrypt it?

Comment: You said: " Enter the encrypted private key in the "Wallet Details" tab. It will prompt you for a password then. " BUT where? Bitcoin QT don't do this...
Electrum don't do this...
Blockchain.info don't do this... SO what wallet do what you say?!? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I found https://github.com/sour-is/bip38tool on github and after a little bit of struggle with the unfamilar golang ecosystem got it installed.

Once installed, the instructions for use are as follows:

```
export BIP38_PASS=<PASSWORD>
cd /usr/local/go/src/bip38tool
./bip38tool decrypt <KEY>
```

This produces your entire decrypted wallet including the plaintext private key which you can import into electrum or any other wallet application.

Comment: "Do not use, broken" warning

Comment: The problem has been fixed... https://github.com/sour-is/bip38tool/issues/1

Answer (score 0):

Enter the encrypted private key in the "Wallet Details" tab. It will prompt you for a password then.

Comment: In case I wasn't the only one confused by this, You'll find the "Wallet Details" tab at bitaddress.org. Do the entropy creation step, and you'll see a tab for this.